# UIImage Aspect Fill when using drawInRect?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I tried to draw scaleAspectFill like contents mode.

I found how to make sacelAspectFit using AVFoundation But I can't find scaleAspectFill.

if I draw horizontal image, I don't know x value

```
image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.init(x: ?, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: displayWidth*(image.size.width/image.size.height), height: displayWidth)))
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming you have an image called `image`, and you want to draw it inside a rectangle `targetRect` so that it fills the rect without being distorted, you can use the following code:

```
let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height
let rect: CGRect
if targetRect.size.width / aspect > targetRect.size.height {
    let height = targetRect.size.width / aspect
    rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: (targetRect.size.height - height) / 2,
                  width: targetRect.size.width, height: height)
} else {
    let width = targetRect.size.height * aspect
    rect = CGRect(x: (targetRect.size.width - width) / 2, y: 0,
                  width: width, height: targetRect.size.height)
}
image.draw(in: rect)
```

Note: this doesn't clip the image, so it will draw outside the edges of the target rect. if you want to clip the image, call `CGContextClipToRect(context, rect)` before drawing.

Note also that the core graphics vertical axis is flipped, with zero starting in the bottom-left instead of top-left compared to UIGraphics, so you may need to flip the rect and clipping rect accordingly.

Comment: You are a life saver!!